# Draw Text using Type1 font in C#

Tags: c#, fonts

I create an application for Font Management and I have a problem with preview of Type1 fonts (.pfb and .pfm ext.). I need any solution how display a text using this font type.

Comment: Which display technology are you using?  Win32?  WinForms?  WPF?

Comment: Type1 is a very old format.  Winforms only supports TrueType.  WPF also supports OpenType.

Answer (score -1):

To draw any font, you can use `Graphics.DrawString` method:

```
System.Drawing.Font font;//initialize your font here.

using (Bitmap previewImage = new Bitmap(16, 16))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(previewImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawString("text", font, Brushes.YellowGreen, location);
    }

    previewImage.Save(@"Your output file path");
}
```